# Not all divs are clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a whiskey passport application for my current job as a way to drive myself to improve my coding "skills". I've encountered a problem in my JS that I can't seem to resolve. Here's a brief overview of my issue: I've created a function to generate a new div element with a click event listener, and it works perfectly for newly added divs. However, the pre-existing divs (items already present in the menu) don't respond to the click events.

JS:

```
// Add click event listener to the new div
    newDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
        newDiv.classList.toggle("clicked"); // Toggle the 'clicked' class
    });
```

```
// Adding the click event listeners to pre-existing div elements
var preExistingDivs = savedItemsDiv.getElementsByClassName("savedItemsDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < preExistingDivs.length; i++) {
    preExistingDivs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("clicked");
    });
```

CSS:

`#saved-items.savedItemsDiv.clicked { background-color: lightpink; }`

I have 'clicked' set to an arbitrary value just so I can scroll through and see it real quick. The thing is, is that the other css for the divs works (size, font, cursor, etc.). I just can't get the listeners to respond to clicks other than for newly added divs. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried various solutions, including setting up a secondary listener for pre-existing divs, but nothing seems to work. I even attempted using ChatGPT for suggestions, but the changes it has recommended ended in a cyclical nightmare.

I've considered creating a separate listener for each pre-existing item, but this would require setting up over 400 individual listeners, which in my opinion sounds like a bad time as well.

Edit with the resolution:

```
// Add click event listener to savedItemsDiv
for(i = 0; i < savedItemsDivs.length; i++){
  savedItemsDivs[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     if (event.target.classList.contains("savedItemsDiv")) {
        event.target.classList.toggle("clicked");
        console.log("clicked this thang");
```

Here's what came up as the solution, thank you to everyone who gave me their advice! Truly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked if `preExistingDivs.length` is 0? You can do so by typing `debugger;` before the `for` loop. If it's 0, then your DOM is not fully rendered when your JS runs. Put the JavaScript below your HTML then. If your divs are build dynamically, make sure your init JS runs after divs have been added to the DOM.

Comment: I recommend doing some basic debugging. `console.log()` your variables to see what their values are before the loop, inside the loop and inside the event handler. The issue could be as simple as you targeting the wrong node or having a typo in a class name.

Comment: do add information by editing the question not by adding them as a comment. Also, use a [repro] (`<>` button or `Ctrl + M`)  to add code to the question.

Comment: PS: Instead using a `for` loop to iterate through your HTML collection object, use `querySelectorAll` + `forEach` much simpler and more performant

Comment: A `delegated event listener` bound to a suitable parent node (`savedItemsDiv`) might be a better approach than registering individual listeners when new elements are added. The delegated listener should inspect the `event.target` to determine if the click originated on a node of interest

Comment: @tacoshy thank you I switched syntax immediately and was much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above: a `delegated listener`, bound to a suitable parent element would be a far better and mor eperformant option than creating a new event listener for every DIV - especially as you mention there would be more than 400 of them.

A single delegated listener can process the `click` event and then, via the `event.target` determine if whatever processing tasks you have should be performed upon that element and it's children or siblings.

The following simply takes the first child element of the parent, clones it and appends to the parent - modifying text in the process. The Event listener applies equally to it and it's predecessors.

```js
const suitable_parent=document.querySelector('#suitable_parent');

suitable_parent.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.closest('div.savedItemsDiv').classList.toggle('clicked');
});

document.querySelector('input[type="button"][id="add"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  let clone=suitable_parent.firstElementChild.cloneNode( true );
      clone.querySelector('p').textContent='Some exciting new content...';
      clone.classList.remove('clicked');
      
  suitable_parent.appendChild( clone );
})
```

```css
body{
  counter-reset:items;
}
#suitable_parent {
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  float: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family:monospace;
}
h6,p{margin:0.1rem 0;}
h6{font-size:0.9rem}
.savedItemsDiv {
  0.25rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0.1rem 0;
  counter-increment:items;
}
.savedItemsDiv h6:before{
  color:green;
  content:counter(items)'] '
}
.savedItemsDiv.clicked {
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='add' value='Add New'>
<div id='suitable_parent'>
  <div class='savedItemsDiv'><h6>A headline</h6><p>lorem ipsum dolor solit...</p></div>
  <div class='savedItemsDiv'><h6>A headline</h6><p>lorem ipsum dolor solit...</p></div>
  <div class='savedItemsDiv'><h6>A headline</h6><p>lorem ipsum dolor solit...</p></div>
  <div class='savedItemsDiv'><h6>A headline</h6><p>lorem ipsum dolor solit...</p></div>
  <div class='savedItemsDiv'><h6>A headline</h6><p>lorem ipsum dolor solit...</p></div>
  <div class='savedItemsDiv'><h6>A headline</h6><p>lorem ipsum dolor solit...</p></div>
</div>
```